# Android - Passing ID from SQLite into a new activity using .putExtra

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I am writing a note taking app within android eclipse. My app currently selects all the notes from within the SQLite database and uses them to populate a ListView. This ListView is clickable, and currently redirects the user to the EditNote activity.

However, I would like to be able to populate the EditTexts within the EditNote activity based on the ID of the ListView note that is clicked.

(So that if I clicked the first ListView Item and it's ID was 2 then the value 2 would be passed through to EditNote)

This would require obtaining the ID of the ListView Item that was clicked, and then passing it through using     .putExtra(); to the EditNote activity.

So my question is: how would I obtain the ID and then pass it through to the EditNote activity? So that I can then use the ID to make additional querys on that activity.

Thank you very much for your time. 
Any additional questions I will answer to the best of my ability.

*Initialising things*

```
    DatabaseHelper dbh;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Context mCtx;
    ListView lv;
```

*onCreate method with onClickListeners*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        refreshData();

        mCtx = this;

        lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

               Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, EditNote.class);
               i.putExtra("ID", listItems.get(position));
               startActivity(i);
        }
        });
```

*refreshData method (used to populate the ListView)*

```
public void refreshData(){

         dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            dbh.open();

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            ArrayList<String[]> searchResult = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            //EditText searchTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchC);

            listItems.clear();

            searchResult = dbh.fetchNotes("");
            //searchResult = dbh.fetchNotes(searchTitle.getText().toString());

            String title = "", note = "", id = "";


            for (int count = 0 ; count < searchResult.size() ; count++) {

                  note = searchResult.get(count)[2];
                  title = searchResult.get(count)[1];
                  id = searchResult.get(count)[0];


                  listItems.add(title);

            }                

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    /*private void setID(String setID) {
        this.id = setID;

    }

    private String getID(){
        return id;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

*DatabaseHelper activity - fetchNotes - used to query the database*

```
public ArrayList<String[]> fetchNotes(String title) throws SQLException {


        ArrayList<String[]> myArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        int pointer = 0;     

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "title",
                "note"}, null, null,
                    null, null, "_id");

        int idColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int titleColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
        int noteColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("note");     

        if (mCursor != null){

           //If possible move to the first record within the cursor
           if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){

                do {
                    //for each record add a new string array to our Array List
                    myArray.add(new String[3]);
                    //
                    myArray.get(pointer)[0] = mCursor.getString(idColumn);
                    //Save the note into the string array
                    myArray.get(pointer)[1] = mCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    //Save the title into the string array
                    myArray.get(pointer)[2] = mCursor.getString(noteColumn);
                    //increment our pointer variable.
                    pointer++;

                } while (mCursor.moveToNext()); // If possible move to the next record

           } else {
               myArray.add(new String[3]);
               myArray.get(pointer)[0] = "";
               myArray.get(pointer)[1] = "";
               myArray.get(pointer)[2] = "";
           }
        } 

        return myArray;
    }
```

*Also here's my create table, just in case*

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "title TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    "note TEXT NOT NULL); ";
```

Comment: You need to get the URI for that particular item in the list view. Since, everything is storing in the database, you should different uris for the items and you can put that uri as your intent extra. This is not an answer but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you also i think your code can be more optimized ...

1. in your fetchNotes() just return the cursor instead of creating ArrayList if suppose you created ArrayList here and it occupies 100 entries again in the caller function you are using the listItems ArrayList... i know android has garbage collector but why to employ it if there is option to avoid ?
2. your myArray is String[] ArrayList but your listItems is not hence you can only access the titles  coz this is wat you are storing here `listItems.add(title);`

   a. So you can either use listItems directly in fetchNotes() like `MainActivity.listitems` (supposing listItem is declared in MainActivity class ) use        after declaring `ArrayList<String[]> listItems=new ArrayList<String[]>();` as `public static ArrayList<String[]> listItems=new ArrayList<String[]>();`
   or

   b. you can simply return the cursor only and do exactly like the myArray type of operation on listItems.

Now you can access the "id" by refering the index you stored the id in listItems.

`listItems.get(position)[2]` ( supposing you stored the id at index 2 ).

I tried to keep it as simple as possible and expect that it will help you ...

Comment: Never suggest to someone they should access a `public static` data member in one `Activity` from another `Activity`. Please remove your suggestion for 2a

Comment: I agree my code be more optimized. For 1. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'returning the cursor', like I'm not sure how this would impact the rest of the fetchNotes() script.  a) I wouldn't know how to implement the use of listItems within the fetchNotes(). b) sounds like the best option, but again I don't know how I would implement this. Thank you very much for your reply, if you could give me some examples or code snippets that would be greatly appreciated. (sorry, I'm new to android).

Comment: @p00pb00b i was just suggest not criticising... 

as for cursor return this is wat i meant 

public Cursor fetchNotes(String title) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "title",
                "note"}, null, null,
                    null, null, "_id");


 return mCursor;

}

Comment: @Squonk i think i got u ... coz then the data member can be manipulated u mean... following the primitive rule of java or oops...

anyways both public static or remove only public ? plz thow some light i always love to learn from my mistakes...

thx

Comment: @Ahmad : You should not use the `public` modifier for fields (variables) or methods in an `Activity` in order to make them accessible by other app components. The reason is that an `Activity` can be destroyed at any time. In rare cases `public static` for primitive data types (int, for example) may be OK but there are safer ways to do it such as using a helper class. Using `public static` should NEVER be done for an object as there is no way to guarantee that object has been initialized and it can cause NullPointerException - it can also cause memory leaks by preventing Garbage Collection.

Comment: @Squonk thx i did got ur point and i had in mind.... :) at places where the storage is guaranteed i prefer to use database. Btw not offend but a static variable stays in the memory till the execution of the prorgram hence i thought we can use it dat way... anyways thanks ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand this completely. Are you not passing the "title" already and your database helper can fetch results using "title"? Is this not working or do you want to optimize it by passing the ID? Even if you want to pass the ID, you can do that using the same mechanism.

Comment: I want to pass the ID from main activity to the editnote activity when the user clicks the ListView Item. So it will pass the ID that relates to the Item they clicked. How would I go about passing the ID? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am sorry but can you make one thing clear. Currently from MainActivity, you are passing **title** of the selected item but instead you want to pass the **ID** of the selcted item? Correct?

Comment: It currently isn't passing title, wheneverr I uncomment the line - i.putExtra("ID", listItems.get(position)); - and uncomment the line within my EditNote activity - String listItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("listItem"); - it causes it to crash upon opening the EditItem activity.

Comment: Okay. You need to redesign the code to make this happen. Create a new Class that contains ID, Title and Note and change fetchNotes to return an ArrayList this new class. Move fetchNotes outside of refreshData into MainActivity and store the results in member variable. Pass this list to refreshData and fill in the list appropriately. Now on list select, get the selected object using the position and the list stored and then pass whatever fields to EditNote. You may need to write a fetchNote method that takes an ID and returns the note.

Comment: Better solution would be also to encapsulate all the data logic into adapter and ask the adapter to give you the selected ID. That way, you don't need to store anything in the main activity. This will require you to design the adapter properly and do all the data management.